# Word boundary matching in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

This Regex Pattern: `\bgoogle\b`

Test case: http://www.google.com/

It matches.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a period represents a word boundary. That is, it is not part of a word, just as a space, a colon, a semicolon, or a tab character are not part of a word. \b is a zero-width assertion, meaning it does not match anything itself, it just defines something about the match.

Comment: Is there any way to specify the word boundary characters ? (in my case it is space)

Comment: You can specify any characters you want. \s represents space characters. So \sgoogle\s will find the word "google" (lower case) surrounded by spaces. That may not be complete enough for all your needs, however, which is why \b may be good to stick with. Note that \bgoogle\b does not match the entire google URL, just the word google within it.

Answer (score 1):

Word boundaries with `\b` are [very tricksy buggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213800/is-there-something-like-a-counter-variable-in-regular-expression-replace/4214173#4214173) indeed!